# Sqoop from Oracle: "Snapshot too Old"

Tags: bigdata, sqoop

I am setting up an automated process to sqoop from an oracle table to an hdfs directory with this command:

```
sqoop-import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@redacted.company.com:1234/db --username redacted --password secret123 --num-mappers 1 --table table --target-dir /data/destination/directory/ --as-avrodatafile --compress --compression-codec org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BZip2Codec
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting the following error message:

```
Error:java.io.IOException: SQLException in nextKeyValue
    ...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01555: snapshot too old: rollback segment number 336 with name "_SYSSMU336_879580159$" too small
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:951)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:208)
```

The business requirement I am attempting to fulfill is that the entire table is imported into our hdfs.  Since we do not own or administrate this database, I lack control over the UNDO tablespace and related parameters.  The job is scheduled to run at 1am which is not a peak time, but since automated processes touch it, I cannot coax people to stop using it during the job.

How should I modify my sqoop-import statement to avoid this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usage of `--num-mappers=10` (i.e. increased parallelism) was sufficient enough to overcome the problem in this instance without impacting the source too much.

Additionally, adding the `--direct` parameter will cause Sqoop to use an Oracle specific connector which will speed things up further, and will be added to my solution as soon as I convince the DBA on that database to open up the necessary privileges.  Direct also supports the option `-Doraoop.import.consistent.read={true|false}` which seems to mirror the Oracle export utility's `CONSISTENT` parameter in function (note, defaults to `false`), in the sense that the undo tablespace would not be used to try to preserve consistency, eliminating the need to race to import before the Undo tablespace fills up altogether.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a Sqoop issue. You would get the same error executing the same statment directly on Oracle. It is an undo tablespace issue. You have to get your query faster or you have to increase the Oracle undo tablespace size.

List of possible fixes:

- Schedule your task when there are less database activity (maybe even
  ask people to stop working for a while).
- Optimize the query that is failing with this error to read less data
  and take less time  Increase the size of the UNDO tablespace.
- Increase the size of the UNDO_RETENTION parameter.
- Set the UNDO tablespace in GUARANTEE mode.
- If you are exporting a table, consider exporting with the
  CONSISTENT=no parameter.
- Do not commit inside a cursor loop

Regards
Giova

Comment: While technically sound, these fixes are not possible for me: The job is already scheduled at non-peak hours, and I do not own the database, nor do I have any administrative rights to mess with the UNDO tablespace and related parameters.  I will need to reach out to the database owners and see if they can provide the export themselves or, in the very least, allow us to use oracle's own export tool to get a hold of the data.